# Using Tinymce as a composer

Tags: email, tinymce, html-entities

I`m using Tiny-MCE as a composer in zimbra web client, when i send an email , tinymce change all HTML tags to HTML entity , something like this :

```
&lt;p style="text-align: center;"&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;<br>
&lt;p style="text-align: center;"&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;<br>
&lt;p style="text-align: center;"&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;<br>
&lt;p style="text-align: center;"&gt;&lt;span style="font-size: xx-large; color: #ffff00; background-color: #000080;"&gt;salam in yek test ast&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;<br>
&lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;<br>
&lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;<br>
&lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;
```

but the original string is :

```
<p style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: xx-large; color: #ffff00; background-color: #000080;">salam in yek test ast</span></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

is there any solution ?

Comment: it isn't tinymce that is doing it, its zimbra. TinyMCE will send you the formatted text, but zimbra with convert all the htmlentities

Comment: How we can prevent this action ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run a function over the content to reformat the htmlentities back to regular characters.